# How to use '?' in java?

Tags: java, operators

I've seen this character being used several times in tutorials and other people's projects, so I would like to know what I would use it for? It's use with 'return' specifically

Comment: Ternary Operator...  About a billion articles online about it.  The google searches *java question mark operator* or just *java question mark* all turn up relevant results.  Is there a reason you asked a question?

Comment: I didn't see those questions when I typed in the title, so I didn't know those existed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are asking about the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) (or [JLS-15.25 Conditional Operator `? :`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)).

```
return (a < b) ? a : b;
```

is *equivalent* to

```
if (a < b) {
    return a;
} else {
    return b;
}
```

While you asked about **`return`** statements, it can also be used in assignments;

```
int t = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

is *equivalent* to

```
int t;
if (a < b) {
    t = a;
} else {
    t = b;
}
```

**or** `int t = Math.min(a, b);`